# Convert IPLimage to h.263 format

Tags: c++, opencv, h.263

I'm using OpenCV for some 2D image processing. I need to convert `IPLimage` (which is captured by camera) to H.263 (*not* h.264) encoded format.

Is there any built-in OpenCV function to achieve this? If not, are there any appropriate APIs that I could use?

Comment: Please don't make all of the text in your question bold. It's obnoxious to look at.

Comment: I don't think OpenCV has a function to do that but I may be wrong. Have you looked at [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

There's **no native way** to do this with OpenCV.

However, you can convert OpenCV frames to what ffmpeg uses and encode it as h263, or do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5825173/176769) guy did using python.

[On this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187745/audio-output-with-video-processing-with-opencv/8191506#8191506), I've showed **how to convert an OpenCV frame to it's FFmpeg equivalent** and display it on a SDL window. There's some code in there that can be quite useful to you.