# How do I stream an openCV video to an HTML webpage?

Tags: c++, python, html, opencv

I am making a robot that will have a webcam on it to provide some simple object detection.  For right now, I would like to simply stream the video to a webpage hosted on the robot and be able to view it from another device. I have written a simple test script in Python ( I will eventually move to C++, my language of choice)  which can get a stream from my webcam, and then do whatever I need with it from there.  The problem then, is that I can't write the video to a file while the app is running, it only writes the file after I quit the script.  I already have a webserver running, and I can write the basic code in HTML to host a video from a file as well, and all of that works.

To summarize:
Is openCV2 in Python and/or C++ capable of livestreaming video using only openCV?
If not, what library would you recommend that I try to take a CV capture object or Mat object and write it to a stream that I can then put on a webpage?
In HTML, is the  tag a good idea to stream video with?

Thank you very much for the advice, I can use all the pointers* I can get!

If you need something clarified/code posted/explanations further than what I have given, please ask and I will do so!

Comment: Have you reviewed any of the JavaScript image/video tools available on github?  CamanJS , Clmtrackr, JS Feat  .. possible to port the matrices from opencv to JS ?  What's the processor on the robot --Rasberry pi, Beaglebone, Intel Edison or something fancier?  Perhaps a motherboard with full featured graphics card (for really fast processing framerates...)?

Comment: Hi sir! How did you solve this problem, I also have the same question. Thanks!

Comment: @BahramdunAdil, technologies have changed... I do believe we're on OpenCV3 now, and HTTP streaming and related protocols have come a long way.  I don't have a solution that will necessarily work for you, but I would suggest trying an existing framework for streaming video, such as an rtmp streamer.  Good luck!

Comment: @PyroAVR Hey there, just stumbled across your question. I'm trying to do the same thing. RTMP Streamer didn't really work out for. You got any approaches?

Answer (score 3):

The issue of streaming frames out of OpenCV and Python has been addressed in the following thread: 
[Pipe raw OpenCV images to FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825173/pipe-raw-opencv-images-to-ffmpeg)

This didn't work for me, but they claim it did for them.

The reason for it not working in my case seems to be that for some output frames additional bytes were added or lost, somewhere between the output to stdout in capture.py and the input to FFMPEG.  Therefore, the number of bytes doesn't correspond to the number of frames.  I am not sure why this is the case.   I used Windows 7.

I will be curious to hear what is your experience if you try this.   I also tried a modified version of capture.py using cv2, and failed for the same reasons.

Answer (score 3):

## Under lab conditions you send full images

You seem to be under lab conditions, so there is a simplistic, yet usable solution, just stream PNG's in Base64 using Websockets. On the client side (web browser) you just receive the base64 images and directly load them into the `src` of an `<img>`. It works for lab scenarios very well, albeit slow.

Comment: Can we add **snapshot** or **record** buttons to the webpage with websockets on the same port?

Comment: yes, Im my case I just send a json every couple of millseconds. { b64:"...", time:"" }. Websockets are bidirectional, so you can ask for snapshots or implement any command you want. I even implemented a start/stop button to stop all the traffic.

Comment: thank you. This is exactly what I am trying to do. The images are sent as `jpg` in `Base64` as socket and read as `src` of an `<img>`. But good to know we can add buttons to the webpage to send requests to the server on the same IP and port.

Comment: Under *lab* conditions it works pretty good, I get >20fps over LAN, quite usable for this scenario. Real video streaming is *a lot* of code overhead and really not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858936/html5-live-streaming) .

So basically you have to use OpenCV capture the frames and pack them into specific formats that fit the streaming protocol, then from your server use HTML5 to put it on the page. You may need to use VLC or FFMepg to pack your cv::Mat. Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that out.  I'm running on an embedded platform (beaglebone) so we'll see how that goes. I'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late, but as I didn't find a completely updated solution for C++ and mjpeg in StackOverflow, thought about writing a new answer.

There are now some good and simple libraries for the task in C++ (c++ mjpg streaming to html)

https://github.com/nadjieb/cpp-mjpeg-streamer

https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer

https://github.com/codewithpassion/mjpg-streamer/tree/master/mjpg-streamer

I found the first one to be very simple. You need CMake, and make installed in the system.

```
git clone https://github.com/nadjieb/cpp-mjpeg-streamer.git;
cd cpp-mjpeg-streamer;
mkdir build && cd build;
cmake ../;
make;
sudo make install;
```

- Make sure you have the correct version of OpenCV installed.

Now, write the streamer:

`mjpeg_server.cc`

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <nadjieb/mjpeg_streamer.hpp>

// for convenience
using MJPEGStreamer = nadjieb::MJPEGStreamer;

int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open("demo.mp4"); 
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        std::cerr << "VideoCapture not opened\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    std::vector<int> params = {cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 90};

    MJPEGStreamer streamer;

    // By default 1 worker is used for streaming
    // if you want to use 4 workers:
    //      streamer.start(8080, 4);
    streamer.start(8000);

    // Visit /shutdown or another defined target to stop the loop and graceful shutdown
    while (streamer.isAlive())
    {
        cv::Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            std::cerr << "frame not grabbed\n";
            //continue;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // http://localhost:8080/bgr
        std::vector<uchar> buff_bgr;
        cv::imencode(".jpg", frame, buff_bgr, params);
        streamer.publish("/bgr", std::string(buff_bgr.begin(), buff_bgr.end()));

        cv::Mat hsv;
        cv::cvtColor(frame, hsv, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

        // http://localhost:8080/hsv
        std::vector<uchar> buff_hsv;
        cv::imencode(".jpg", hsv, buff_hsv, params);
        streamer.publish("/hsv", std::string(buff_hsv.begin(), buff_hsv.end()));

        // std::cout<< "published" << std::endl;
    }

    streamer.stop();
}
```

Write the `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(mjpeg_streamer CXX)

find_package(OpenCV 4.2 REQUIRED)
find_package(nadjieb_mjpeg_streamer REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(stream_test
  "mjpeg_server.cc")
target_compile_features(stream_test PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
target_link_libraries(stream_test PRIVATE nadjieb_mjpeg_streamer::nadjieb_mjpeg_streamer
                     ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

```
| --- mjpeg_server.cc
| --- CMakeLists.txt
| --- ...
| --- build  
      | --- demo.mp4
      | --- ...
```

Now, we can build the streamer.

```
mkdir build && cd build;
cmake ../;
make;
./stream_test
```

Now, if you go to `"http://ip_address:port/bgr"` or, `"http://ip_address:port/hsv"` you should be able to see the stream. In my case, ip = 192.168.1.7 / localhost, port = 8000.

If you want to grab the stream with another server,

`index.html`

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="http://localhost:8000/bgr">
    <img src="http://localhost:8000/hsv">
  </body>
</html>
```

`serve.py`

```
import http.server
import socketserver

class MyHttpRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = 'index.html'
        return http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

# Create an object of the above class
handler_object = MyHttpRequestHandler

PORT = 8080
my_server = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), handler_object)

# Star the server
my_server.serve_forever()
```

`python3 serve.py`

Finally, even though it's extremely simple, it's not secure.