# OpenCV create Output Stream

Tags: c++, opencv, mjpeg

I'm working on a Project where I capture a Video using OpenCv on a Raspberry Pi and Process it. What I want is to create an Output Stream of this Processed Video. I'm working together on this with a buddy of mine. He creates a Website/Web-server on the device which should be able to view the Stream I create. Is there any way openCV is able to create an Output Stream? 
I don't want to create a Video nor do i want to write single Frames as "Images" to the File-System because this is way to slow.

Comment: I already tried to implement a udp Socket.... but my buddy cant think of any method how to implement data from the socket as video/live stream on the "website"

Comment: Probably these can help: http://answers.opencv.org/question/26202/generate-video-output-streaming/ http://answers.opencv.org/question/22010/how-sent-a-live-streamudp-of-frames-captured-by-opencv/#22043 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205358/how-do-i-stream-an-opencv-video-to-an-html-webpage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the End I figured out that OpenCV is not capable of creating an Output-Live Video Stream. Its only possible to render a Video to File.

Instead i created my own little Http Motion-JPEG Stream
[How to Create a HTTP MJPEG Streaming Server With QTcp-Server Sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064955/how-to-create-a-http-mjpeg-streaming-server-with-qtcp-server-sockets)

I also want to Mention that VLC provides a very powerful Backend / libs.
[C++ LibVLC Create Stream from Frames/Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995719/c-libvlc-create-stream-from-frames-images)

Another Soloution could be to use GStreamer if you are on Linux