# Darkened colors when writing video in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video, colors

I'm writing a small script that shows some things in Pygame and then writes those same things to a video using OpenCV with Python. The weird thing is that I noticed that the colors in the video showed slightly darker.

So I wrote a simpler program that  writes a basic video with a dark background and a blue square moving horizontally. I took a snapshot from the video and compared its BGR values with the ones specified in the program. They were, in fact, darker.

It's the first time I play with writing videos so I don't know much about colorspaces, so maybe this is something obvious but I haven't found the solution to match both colors.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cv2 import VideoWriter, VideoWriter_fourcc

# Video parameters
width = 1920
height = 1080
fps = 30
seconds = 5
video = VideoWriter('./square.avi', VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), float(fps), (width, height))

# Square parameters
cellHeight = 100
cellWidth = 500
xPos = 100
yPos = 100
cellColor = (255, 194, 102)   # BGR, ends up as (255, 188, 92) in the written frames
backroundColor = (25, 25, 25) # BGR, ends up as (22, 25, 23)

# Frame loop
for _ in range(seconds * fps):

    frame = np.empty((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    frame[:,:] = backroundColor

    pt1 = (xPos, yPos)                         # NW corner
    pt2 = (xPos + cellWidth, yPos + cellWidth) # SE corner

    cv2.rectangle(frame, pt1=pt1, pt2=pt2, color=cellColor, thickness=-1)
    video.write(frame)
    xPos += 10

video.release()
```

Here you can see the difference between pygame and the video. Despite it is not the same frame, you can see the different colors, especially the green and red.

[image]

Comment: Maybe some problems with encoder. Can you try `VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')` for codec?

Comment: @Gralex It seems I can't use avc1 as I installed opencv through pip. I've read that I must build OpenCV from source to be able to use it. I'm looking on how to do it.

Comment: Ok, I built from source, used avc1 but the colors still show darker.

Comment: mp4v aka MPEG-4 uses a lossy compression. You may try to read your video file with `VideoCapture` and see that the background color is not `25 25 25` (`21 24 22` on my machine). If you use [HFYU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769025/704244) lossless codec (`VideoWriter_fourcc(*'HFYU')`), then you should get `25 25 25` back again.

Comment: Yes, I think that's it. Both mpeg-4 and AVC1 share the same problem, but HFYU shows the color correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @bartolo-otrit put you comment as an answer so it can easily be seen, ta.

Comment: Yes, and so I can select it as the answer.

Comment: Perhaps a difference in color profiles.

Comment: @DrBwts A lossless codec isn't a solution in my opinion (because of the output size), it's just an explanation. You may try to use ffmpeg [filters](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20962/ffmpeg-color-correction-gamma-brightness-and-saturation) to increase brightness. If it's the way to go, then the answers from [Pipe raw OpenCV images to FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825173/pipe-raw-opencv-images-to-ffmpeg) could help.